# wrong text file output of special characters using UTF-8 enconding in R 3.1.2 with Mac OS X

Tags: r, csv, encoding, utf-8

I am having problems to write a csv file with Spanish accents, using R 3.1.2 and Mac OS X 10.6.

I cannot write words with accents into text file.

When I do:

```
con <- file("y.csv",encoding="UTF-8")
write.csv("Ú",con)
```

I get y.csv file which has the following content:

"","x"
"1","√ö"

Ie, "√ö" instead of "Ú".

When using `write.table` the outcome is equivalent.

Encoding("Ú") is "UTF-8"

If I do `write.xlsx("Ú","y.xlsx")` I get y.xlsx file which successfully shows Ú.

I have also tried to convert to other encodings using `iconv()` with no success.

I have set default encoding "UTF-8" in RStudio and on TextEdit. When using only R (not RStudio) the problem is the same.
In RStudio the special characters appear correctly (in files), and also in the console in R.

`Sys.getlocale()`gives

```
"es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8/C/es_ES.UTF-8/es_ES.UTF-8"
```

In Mac OS X Terminal

```
file -I y.csv
```

gives

```
y.csv: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

I don't see where the problem is. Any help, please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export UTF-8 BOM to .csv in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402307/export-utf-8-bom-to-csv-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this other question that seems like a near duplicate to this one :

[Export UTF-8 BOM to .csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402307/export-utf-8-bom-to-csv-in-r#)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not one of codification in R, but from TextEdit, which did not show the right characters, although I had selected UTF-8 codification in preferences. Got solved using a different editor. I was using Mac OS X 10.6.8 and TextEdit 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you cán write words with accents, but Excel expects a different encoding. Try writing your csv with for example `write_csv()`, and open the csv with a workaround:

- open Excel
- then choose tab Data | Get External Data | From Text
- choose your file
- and in step 1 of the text import wizard,  choose file origin 65001: Unicode(UTF8).

See also http://www.openforis.org/support/questions/279/wrong-characters-display-when-exporting-files-to-csv-from-collect