# Incorrect encoding of special characters with write.csv()

Tags: r

I'm working with a dataframe that was originally generated using `read_excel()`. The dataframe contains special characters like "ö", which are displayed correctly within R.

```
write.csv(data, "data.csv", fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

This command turns special characters like "ö" into incorrect CSV output like "Ã¶".

There are similar questions where it is advised to set encoding to UTF-8, which I have done here (if I remove the `fileEncoding` command, it doesn't make a difference).

I get the same issue with

```
write_csv(data, "data.csv")
```

I am viewing the CSV in Microsoft Excel, which displays special characters correctly if I open other files. I am running R on Windows.

**Edit**: I resolved it by using `fileEncoding = "UTF-16"`. UTF-8 should work for German characters, though, so the problem is a bit odd.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Export UTF-8 BOM to .csv in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402307/export-utf-8-bom-to-csv-in-r) If not, could you edit your question to include precisely why the supplied answers dont work? Good luck!

Comment: How are the values actually encoded? How did you import them/create them in the first place? How are you reviewing the context of the CSV? Are you sure that program in using the correct encoding?

Comment: The UTF-8 code for "ö" is (hex) c3 b6  but if it is viewed with an ASCII editor with lets say windows 1252 encoding you see  c3="Ã" and b6="¶".

It all gets clearer when you view the stuff with a hex editor viewer... And I had noticed problems with the Notepad++ hex plugin,  Its maybe better to use a dedicated hex editor/viewer...